# Best Practice WIX Conditional Install versions of software

Tags: c#, .net, wix

I have a plugin (service that runs in the background) that I need to install on various computers. And I need to install a different version of the service based on which .Net version they have installed.

.Net 3.5 gets 3.5 version of plugin
.Net 4.5 gets 4.5 version of plugin, etc.

I know how to detect .Net versions in WIX using the various NETFRAMEWORK... properties, but I'm having trouble with it installing all versions of the plugin instead of the one I want.

```
<Feature Id="ProductFeature451" Title="Plugin" Level="1">
            <Condition Level="1">
                <![CDATA[REMOVE~="ALL" OR (NETFRAMEWORK45 >= "#378675")]]>
            </Condition>
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents451" />
        </Feature>

        <Feature Id="ProductFeature40" Title="Plugin" Level="1">
            <Condition Level="1">
                <![CDATA[REMOVE~="ALL" OR (NETFRAMEWORK45 < "#378675" AND NETFRAMEWORK40FULL) ]]>
            </Condition>
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents40" />
        </Feature>

        <Feature Id="ProductFeature351" Title="Plugin" Level="1">
            <Condition Level="1">
                <![CDATA[REMOVE~="ALL" OR (NETFRAMEWORK35 AND NOT NETFRAMEWORK45 AND NOT NETFRAMEWORK40FULL) ]]>
            </Condition>
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents351" />
        </Feature>
```

I tried using "Installed" instead of REMOVE~="ALL", but same issue. Do I have the  in the wrong place?

In earlier attempts, I ran into the "reference count" issues, because I was trying to install the various plugins into the same directory, so now I'm trying to install into different directories based on version of plugin.

It's actually not the end of the world to install all of the versions, but I need to have the service only created/running for the proper version.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out the issue.

The features needed to start out with a Level = "0" (not installed). Then the condition will mark them as Level="1" when met and thus will be installed.

```
 <Feature Id="ProductFeature351" Title="Plugin" Level="0">
            <Condition Level="1">
                <![CDATA[REMOVE~="ALL" OR (NETFRAMEWORK35 AND NOT NETFRAMEWORK45 AND NOT NETFRAMEWORK40FULL) ]]>
            </Condition>
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents351" />
        </Feature>
```